# Jssor slider transitions

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

I'm trying to implement a transition effect on my Jssor slider, but I'm unsure where to place the options.

The website has a transition code generator which I used, but no matter where I seem to place the code the slider doesn't use the transition.

This is my current attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var options =
            {
                $DragOrientation: 3,
                $AutoPlay: true,
                $SlideDuration: 1500,
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4500,
                $SlideshowOptions: {
                    $Transitions: { $Duration: 600, $Delay: 50, $Cols: 8, $Rows: 4, $FlyDirection: 5, $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag, $Assembly: 1028, $ChessMode: { $Column: 3, $Row: 12 }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2 }
                }
            }
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('banner_slider', options);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to find a working example and found out the correct format:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var _SlideshowTransitions = [{
            $Duration: 600,
            $Delay: 50,
            $Cols: 8,
            $Rows: 4,
            $FlyDirection: 5,
            $Formation:
            $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationZigZag,
            $Assembly: 1028,
            $ChessMode: { $Column: 3, $Row: 12 },
            $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad },
            $Opacity: 2
        }];
        var options = {
            $DragOrientation: 3,
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $SlideDuration: 1500,
            $AutoPlayInterval: 4500,
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //Options which specifies enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //Transitions to play slide, see jssor slideshow transition builder
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: 2,                                   //0 After Slideshow, 2 Always
                $ContentMode: false                             //Whether to trait content as slide, otherwise trait an image as slide
            }
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("banner_slider", options);
    });
</script>
```