# Multiple Slider for JSSOR

Tags: jssor

I manage to make a slider with multiple image to show. Here is my created slider:

[image]

But the effects is only sliding from right to left. I've already tried what stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21193513/13445324) that copied the code [here](https://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html).Below code is my transition codes.

```
oMultipleJssorOptions: {
  $AutoPlay: this.iAutoTransition,
  $AutoPlaySteps: 3,
  $SlideWidth: this.iWidth,
  $SlideSpacing: 45,
  $Align: 5,
  $ArrowKeyNavigation: 1,
  $PlayOrientation: 1,
  $DragOrientation: 1,
  $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
       $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
       $ChanceToShow: 2,
       $Steps: 4
  },
  $BulletNavigatorOptions: {
       $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,
       $ChanceToShow: 3,
       $Steps: 4,
        $SpacingX: 16
   }
 }
```

### Edit

This please see the gif for the created transition [image: gif]

Answer (score 0):

Please specify different id for each individual slider.

e.g. if the first slider is `jssor_1`, the second slider can be `jssor_2` then. That's to say, you'd replace all `jssor_1` with `jssor_2` in the code of the second slider.

Comment: I only have one slider with multiple banner to show

    <div :id="sJssorId" :style="sJssorStyle">
          <div>First Rectengle banner</div>
          <div>Second Rectengle banner</div>
          <div>Third Rectengle banner</div>
    </div>

Comment: Treat them as different sliders and make it work first. After that, you can remove duplicate css.